# Data is getting loaded on the UI after a lag

Tags: angular, typescript

I am working on code to get a list on UI but the list is getting loading very slowly. The data comes from .NET Core2 API. What can be the better way of writing this code to avoid delays in list loading?

```
service.ts
--------------------
public getMyList(): Observable<IMyList[]> {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.get(this.url + '/list', { headers }).pipe(
      map((result: IMyList[]) => {
        if (result && Object.keys(result).length > 0) {
          return result;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      })
    );
  }

component.ts
--------------------
public myList: IMyList[] = [];


public getMyList(): void {
    this.service.getMyList().subscribe(
      (result: IMyList[]) => { this.myList = result; }
    );
  }

component.html
----------------------------------------
    <tr class="tableRow" *ngFor="let list of myList = index">
      <td class="orgCell">{{list.col1}}</td>
      <td>{{list.col2}}</td>
      <td>
        <label [ngClass]="{'cellStatusInUse':list.col5,'cellStatusNotInUse' : !list.col5}"></label>
        &nbsp; {{code.col5 === true ? 'In use' : 'Not used'}}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
map((result: IMyList[]) => {
        if (result && Object.keys(result).length > 0) {
          return result;
        } else {
          return [];
        }
      })
```

This is wrong map operator usage. Map function passes each source value through a transformation function to get corresponding output values.
Read more [here](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#instance-method-map)

I think your code should look like

```
service.ts
--------------------
public getMyList() {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders({
      'Accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    });

    return this.http.get(this.url + '/list', { headers });
  }

component.ts
--------------------
public myList: Observable<IMyList[]> = of([]);


public getMyList(): void {
    this.myList = this.service.getMyList().pipe(
      map(item => { return item; })
    );
  }

component.html
----------------------------------------
    <tr class="tableRow" *ngFor="let list of myList | async; let i = index;">
      <td class="orgCell">{{list.col1}}</td>
      <td>{{list.col2}}</td>
      <td>
        <label [ngClass]="{'cellStatusInUse':list.col5,'cellStatusNotInUse' : !list.col5}"></label>
        &nbsp; {{code.col5 === true ? 'In use' : 'Not used'}}
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Also, you should receive an empty array from the server instead of null or undefined

Comment: On removing map operator from service.ts, it gives the following error:Type 'Observable<Object>' is not assignable to type 'Observable<IMyList[]>'.
  Type 'Object' is not assignable to type 'IMyList[]'.
    The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
      Property 'includes' is missing in type 'Object'.

Comment: Sorry, I made some mistakes. I have updated the code

Comment: Sorry but it still gives an error Type 'Observable<any[]>' is not assignable to type 'IMyList[]' at public myList: IMyList[] = of([]) and at this.myList = this.service.getMyList().pipe(
      map(item => { return item; })
    );

Comment: The code now works fine but there is no improvement in performance. Still taking time.

Comment: You will have the delay because of you make HTTP request

Answer (score 0):

I think the code is simple, it should not cause any problem. The problem is your backend and how to present your code.

1. Can you check the code on Web API you mentioned above? If the load time is too long, can you do any thing to improve the API performance.
2. If there are too many data. For example 10.000 rows. You should do the pagination on Web API. And on Front End you can add infinity scrolling feature. It will boost the load time a lot.

Comment: The Web API code has been tested(not by me though as I don't have much knowledge about ASP.NET Core) and it works fine. Some problem with the UI which I am unable to find. There are only 3 records and it takes around 2 seconds to load it. For first 2 secs, it shows "no record found" which should be the message if there are no records. And then it shows the list.